# Trouble with multiple SELECT in SQL can't figure out where

Tags: mysql, sql

Having trouble with SQL, lack of knowledge. How can I merge those two query's together? On there own each query is working just fine, what need to be done so those two query's return one row (works together)?

Query 1

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=1 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (01, 02, 03) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a_I,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=1 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (04, 05, 06) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as a_II,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=1 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (07, 08, 09) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as a_III,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=1 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (10, 11, 12) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as a_IV,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=2 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (01, 02, 03) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b_I,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=2 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (04, 05, 06) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b_II,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=2 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (07, 08, 09) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b_III,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=2 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (10, 11, 12) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b_IV,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (01, 02, 03) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_I,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (04, 05, 06) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_II,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (07, 08, 09) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_III,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (10, 11, 12) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_IV,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND flight_user=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as a_total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND flight_user=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b_total
    FROM flight_data;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(touchdown_time, takeoff_time)))) FROM flight_data WHERE YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND flight_user=1) AS a_total_time,
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(touchdown_time, takeoff_time)))) FROM flight_data WHERE YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND flight_user=2) AS b_total_time;
```

Comment: Without knowing what you want to do, what your data looks like, what results you want, and the database you are using, you are not providing enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: Take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58982106/edit) your question with additional detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work but what will be returned I do not know as well what you want to get from this I do not know... So if you give us some more data then I can help more... Cheers! One more thing, this will work in MySQL and we do not know if you do use MySQL so also please do tag database. Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=1 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (01, 02, 03) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a_I,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=1 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (04, 05, 06) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as a_II,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=1 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (07, 08, 09) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as a_III,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=1 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (10, 11, 12) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as a_IV,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=2 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (01, 02, 03) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b_I,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=2 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (04, 05, 06) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b_II,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=2 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (07, 08, 09) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b_III,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flight_user=2 AND YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (10, 11, 12) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b_IV,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (01, 02, 03) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_I,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (04, 05, 06) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_II,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (07, 08, 09) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_III,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND MONTH(flight_date) in (10, 11, 12) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_IV,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND flight_user=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as a_total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND flight_user=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b_total,
    (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(touchdown_time, takeoff_time)))) FROM flight_data WHERE YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND flight_user=1) AS a_total_time,
    (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(touchdown_time, takeoff_time)))) FROM flight_data WHERE YEAR(flight_date)='2019' AND flight_user=2) AS b_total_time
    FROM flight_data;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0cd32d24c746b361b700269c1048b64e)

Comment: Sorry for lack of information, but this is exactly what I needed. Thank you, so close to solution but just can't get there. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. P.S. You now can also vote up answers and questions because you have >15 points . I am happy it helped. Cheers!